# Minor Arc Estimates for an Exponential Sum for a Quadratic Polynomial Over the Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, reference-request

Let $f$ be a quadratic polynomial with leading coefficient $\alpha$, and suppose $\alpha$ is in a "minor arc" in the sense that $\alpha$ is not within $\frac{(\log N)^A}{q N^2}$ of any rational number $\frac{a}{q}$ with $q < (\log N)^A$.  My advisor told me that the following holds:

$\sum_{n=1}^N \Lambda(n) e(f(n)) \lesssim N (\log N)^{-C(A)}$

Where $\Lambda$ is the Von Mangoldt function and $C$ is some unbounded increasing function in $A$.  Could someone please help me find a reference for this statement?

Comment: Added tag [reference-request]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result (or at least the method) probably goes back to Vinogradov or Davenport. For an explicit statement/proof of this result you can see, for instance, Theorem 1 in:

[J. Liu, T. Zhan, Estimation of exponential sums over primes in short intervals. I. Monatsh. Math. 127 (1999), no. 1, 27–41.](http://www.springerlink.com/content/pu5carvlgfx4r9cu/?MUD=MP)

This work focuses on proving more general results (in particular, the analogous result in the interval $[x,x+y]$ with $x^{11/16+\epsilon} \leq y \leq x$). This, however, should imply your statement by setting $y=x$ and dyadically decomposing $[1,N]$.

The paper also discusses related work which might be useful.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/s006050050020](https://doi.org/10.1007/s006050050020) ([Zbl 0922.11070](https://zbmath.org/0922.11070)).